# Three.js ply not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to display my ply modifying three.js webgl_loader_ply example, but it is not showing anything. I can see the object when I open the ply with MeshLab. I have tried to zoom out, change the camera angle, disable the shadowedlight to no avail. Any more tips?

Below is the edited webgl_loader_ply.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - PLY</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;

            }

            a { color: skyblue }
            .button { background:#999; color:#eee; padding:0.2em 0.5em; cursor:pointer }
            .highlight { background:orange; color:#fff; }

            span {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 60px;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="info">
            <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> -
            PLY loader test by <a href="https://github.com/menway">Wei Meng</a>. Image from <a href="http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/ply/ply.html">John Burkardt</a>
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/PLYLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container, stats;

            var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15 );
                camera.position.set( 3, 0.15, 3  );

                cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, -0.1, 0 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x72645b );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x72645b, 2, 15 );


                // Ground

                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 40, 40 ),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, specular: 0x101010 } )
                );
                plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
                plane.position.y = -0.5;
                scene.add( plane );

                plane.receiveShadow = true;


                // PLY file

                var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
                loader.load( './models/ply/binary/foot.ply', function ( geometry ) {

                    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.y = - 0.2;
                    mesh.position.z =   0.3;
                    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.001 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );


                // Lights

                scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0x443333, 0x111122 ) );

                addShadowedLight( 1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 1.35 );
                addShadowedLight( 0.5, 1, -1, 0xffaa00, 1 );

                // renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // stats

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                // resize

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function addShadowedLight( x, y, z, color, intensity ) {

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );
                directionalLight.position.set( x, y, z );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                directionalLight.castShadow = true;

                var d = 1;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;

                directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4;

                directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
                directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;

                directionalLight.shadow.bias = -0.005;

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

                camera.position.x = Math.sin( timer ) * 2.5;
                camera.position.z = Math.cos( timer ) * 2.5;

                camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see it if you comment out the lines

```
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.001 );
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is the reason for the .ply model not displaying with these lines.

Comment: it was not that the model was not displaying but more that the camera was inside the model looking at the models back-faces. The first line just changes the orientation and the second makes the model smaller.